# PSQL slower than PgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've been profiling some part of my application and I've found out that
PgAdmin3 is significantly faster than psql at executing the exact same script.
I'm using unix sockets, Ubuntu 12.04 and Postgresql 9.1 and pgadmin3 v1.14. I have a simple script like the following:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO key_value(section,key,value) VALUES('section','key1','value');
....
INSERT INTO key_value(section,key,value) VALUES('section','key10000','value');
COMMIT;
```

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE key_value
(
  key text NOT NULL,
  value text,
  CONSTRAINT key_value_pkey PRIMARY KEY (section , key )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

There are 10000 inserts in this script. Executing it in pgadmin3 takes around 0.5 seconds, executing it in psql takes 2.5~3.5 seconds. Both are wrapped in a transaction so there should be really no difference. Results are consistent afer recreating the table, doing a full vacuum etc. Logging in the Postgresql server shows postgres doing a log for every insert statement when being executed in psql but only one log when being executed from pgadmin3.

psql execution is done with the following:

```
psql  -n -t -f p.sql -o/dev/null
```

and also tested with

```
psql  -n -t -1 -f p.sql -o/dev/null
```

My question is why is psql so much slower and why us postgresql logging each and every statement in one client but only the whole transaction in the other and wether there is a simple fix to psql.

**EDIT** Just to clarify, I'm logging the duration not the statement:

In the server I'm getting the following when executing with psql

```
2012-10-02 12:20:32 CEST LOG:  duration: 0.283 ms
....
2012-10-02 12:20:35 CEST LOG:  duration: 0.285 ms
2012-10-02 12:20:35 CEST LOG:  duration: 0.291 ms
2012-10-02 12:20:35 CEST LOG:  duration: 0.279 ms
2012-10-02 12:20:35 CEST LOG:  duration: 0.284 ms
2012-10-02 12:20:35 CEST LOG:  duration: 0.279 ms
2012-10-02 12:20:35 CEST LOG:  duration: 0.299 ms
....
2012-10-02 12:20:36 CEST LOG:  duration: 5.779 ms
```

When executing with pgadmin3:

```
2012-10-02 12:23:21 CEST LOG:  duration: 532.695 ms
```

User and database are the same in psql and pgadmin3

Comment: While not an answer, your problem is "10000 inserts in this script". Use [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), or at least multi-valued inserts. As for different logging - maybe you used `ALTER USER ... SET log_statement = 'all'` and you're using different users with psql and PgAdmin? Or maybe you have a `set` in your `psqlrc`?

Comment: Yes I realize that (and there are other solutions like multrow inserts, etc), but the application is right now using a legacy store and doing that would require rearchitecturing the application.

Comment: Just checked and there is no psqlrc or ALTER USER statement.

Comment: What if you remove the BEGIN and COMMIT and pass psql this option --single-transaction?

Comment: That's the second invocation in my comment (the -1 option). Anyway I tried what you suggested and it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My tip: pgAdmin execute script as one multistatement - so there is less network (protocol) overhead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Is there a way to make psql to execute it as a multistatement?

Comment: Could that also explain the logging differences?

Comment: psql can execute multistatement entered as -c parameter from command line, but it is limited. So you can use just multiinsert - you should to use only one semicolon, that is statement delimiter.

Comment: @CraigRinger, yes it explain a difference in log. you can try: #1 echo 'select 1; select 2' | psql postgres #2 psql -c "select 1; select 2" postgres

Comment: @PavelStehule As you say the -c command line is limited. I could multinsert but that would require architectural changes to the app, so I would like to see if there is a way to test whether it's multi statements that is doing the trick. Anybody knows of another app that can send it as such?

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer since I've tested building one huge string and sending it to postgresql instead of sending the statements and I've seen the same performance improvement as in pgadmin3. It would be nice if there was a way to tell the client to group transaction queries in one huge string and sending them in one step though.

Comment: I would post your case on the PostgreSQL forums and let the brains behind the database see if there is logical reason for this behavior or if it's just never been an issue for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

`psql` has a integrated parser that recognizes the semi-colon as a statement separator. It uses it to break down the SQL script into multiple statements, contrary to pgadmin, as said in [Pavel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689473/238814).

There's no option to turn off this behavior. However, the use of a DO anonymous code block should achieve similar results with little changes. If you wrote the script like this:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO key_value(section,key,value) VALUES('section','key1','value');
....
INSERT INTO key_value(section,key,value) VALUES('section','key10000','value');
END $$;
```

This would be sent to the server in one go as with pgadmin (although it's technically quite different), and presumably be executed in a comparable time.

EDIT: as per @vseguip comment, this is not efficient because of the time spent by the plpgsql interpreter on those 10k statements.

ALTERNATIVE IDEA: change the script to have only one INSERT with multiple rows as opposed to multiple INSERTs, no DO block.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO key_value(section,key,value) VALUES('section','key1','value'),
      ('section','key2','value'),
      ('section','key3','value'),
      ....
      ('section','key10000','value');
END;
```

Comment: For some reason (I guess having to "compile" the anonymous function) this is slower than regular psql 10s vs 3.5s.

Comment: @vseguip: too bad. I've updated the answer with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, but using multivalued insert would require rearchitecturing of the application.As it stands my best bet would be to group queries within a transaction in one huge string and send them in one query.

Comment: This solution worked well for me, but the syntax is actually:
`INSERT INTO key_value(section,key,value) VALUES
      ('section','key1','value'),
      ....
      ('section','key10000','value');`. That is `VALUES` is written only once.

Comment: @MartinP: my bad. It's now fixed in the answer, thanks for pointing this out.